# why use symbols before version in bower dependences ?

Tags: bower

Why use "^", "~", "#" in bower dependencies??? What is the difference of each command before version??

EX:
 "angular-aria": "~1.5.5",
 "bootstrap-sass": "~3.3.6",
 "angular-bootstrap": "^1.3.2",
 "moment": "^2.13.0",
 "rdash-ui": "#1.0.1",

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [package.json documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json), for more info please refer to http://semver.org/

- version Must match version exactly
- >version Must be greater than version
- >=version etc
- < version
- <=version
- ~version "Approximately equivalent to version" See semver
- ^version "Compatible with version" See semver
- 1.2.x 1.2.0, 1.2.1, etc., but not 1.3.0
- http://... See 'URLs as Dependencies' below
- asterisk (*) Matches any version
- "" (just an empty string) Same as *
- version1 - version2 Same as >=version1 <=version2.
- range1 || range2 Passes if either range1 or range2 are satisfied.
- git ... See 'Git URLs as Dependencies' below
- user/repo See 'GitHub URLs' below
- tag A specific version tagged and published as tag See npm-tag
- path/path/path See Local Paths below